# tcolorbox breakable raster does not work if a cell breaks

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to create a raster of 4 boxes with random content length. They all must to have the same height, so I have the following code:

```
\begin{tcbraster}[breakable, enhanced, raster equal height ,raster columns=4]
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    Column 1
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    Column 2
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    Column 3
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum{1}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
```

The problem comes when a box is too large and breaks. Then the column layout is ignored, rendering the boxes vertically.

[image: Result]

Has anyone faced a similar problem? Is there a solution?

Comment: raster aligns boxes. I doubt very much that you can use it with breakable. If you really need to split the boxes you could check the magazine library.

Comment: I agree with Ulrike Fischer. `breakable` cannot be combined with a `raster`.

Comment: What a shame. I am going to take a look to the magazine library. Thank you